# Secret_key_base isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Daniel Keogh's learn rails tutorial and am completely stuck on setting up the secret key. I've set up the following in my .bashrc file:

```
    export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export GMAIL_USERNAME="entered my gmail here"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="and pass here"
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="key here"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="id here"
export OWNER_EMAIL="as per above"
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="754735714c2b591df6fedeeba6b6d0a118ce6d9cb01382022f01d2f1be5ac97143204c9726d37ab44b516542ed49a0a17e671b5b9b9100dd902140c164695859"
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"`enter code here`
```

I then set up my secrets file like this:

```
    development:

email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
domain_name: example.com
owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
secret_key_base: 754735714c2b591df6fedeeba6b6d0a118ce6d9cb01382022f01d2f1be5ac97143204c9726d37ab44b516542ed49a0a17e671b5b9b9100dd902140c164695859

test:
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.

production:
email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

When I start the web server I get this:

Internal Server Error

Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.1/2014-02-24) at 0.0.0.0:3000

Can't find any answers online and now been stuck on this for days! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your real indentation of `secrets.yml` ? YAML is very strict with indentation.

Comment: sorry how do you mean real indentation?

Comment: ah do you mean the ""? If so thats exactly as I have it written - should I lose the "" marks around the key in the .bashrc file?

Comment: The number of spaces before the text at each line : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style .

Comment: sorry but I'm still confused, I've got 1 space after the : and then have put in a secret key without any " " marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation should be like

```
development:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  domain_name: example.com
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base:     754735714c2b591df6fedeeba6b6d0a118ce6d9cb01382022f01d2f1be5ac97143204c9726d37ab44b516542ed49a0a17e671b5b9b9100dd902140c164695859

test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  # Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
  # instead read values from the environment.

production:
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
  mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
  mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Ah you legend! Can't believe it was as simple as that. One thing though, to get it working from .bashrc could I put secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %> in development - i.e. have I got the indentation in the .bashrc file correct? Really really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I never had work with `.bashrc`. All that I know is that you probably don't need to indent anything ; put all text to left.

Answer (score 1):

I had been having the same issue and I am also running my ENV under ZSH. I needed to include the information from the Book in two places.

.bash_profile
.zshrc

I used the same import using hard coded variables in these two locations.
**(Removed Personal Data for Answer)**

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="*********************"
export GMAIL_USERNAME="**************"
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="**********"
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="***********-us9"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="***********"
export OWNER_EMAIL="****@example.com"
```

Then I set up the secrets.yml file using the:

```
development:
email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
domain_name: example.com
owner_email: <%= ENV["OWNER_EMAIL"] %>
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Shutdown the Terminal and restarted Terminal, restarted server and I am able to submit to Google Drive